# How to solve Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')? Paging using react, MUI and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, material-ui, frontend

I'm developing code that aims to show a limited number of cards per page based on the amount of data stored in a JSON file. I expected that clicking on the ">" or "<" icon would go to the next or previous page respectively changing the cards.

My App.tsx looked like this:

```
import { default as data } from "./DATA.json" //contains an array of json objects.

let [page, setPage] = useState(1); //is a state that stores the beginning of pagination.

const PER_PAGE = 8; //stores how many cards will be displayed per page.

const totalPages= Math.ceil(data.length / PER_PAGE); //stores the total number of pages

import { usePagination } from "./Pagination"; 
//is a component that receives as parameter data and PER_PAGE. Inside the component there are 4 functions:

currentData(); //get current data from JSON
jump(); //jump to the next page
next(); //show the contents of the next page
prev(); //show the contents of the previous page

const _DATA = usePagination(data, PER_PAGE);
```

Ps: In the component usePagination.tsx I passed the DataBooks interface for the data and itemsPerPage parameters, however, the error *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')* appears. The result I wanted was not achieved (change cards accordingly as you go to the next or previous page) because I don't know what it is. Someone help me please I don't know what to do.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Books from "./interfaces";

interface DataBooks {
  data: Books[];
  itemsPerPage: number;
}

export const usePagination = ({ data, itemsPerPage }: DataBooks) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const maxPage = Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage);

  function currentData() {
    const begin = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    const end = begin + itemsPerPage;
    return data.slice(begin, end);
  }

  function next() {
    setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.min(currentPage + 1, maxPage));
  }

  function prev() {
    setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.max(currentPage - 1, 1));
  }

  function jump(page: number) {
    const pageNumber = Math.max(1, page);
    setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.min(pageNumber, maxPage));
  }
  return { next, prev, jump, currentData, currentPage, maxPage };
};
```

[Code in codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-mui-typescript-suli37?file=/src/UsePagination.tsx)

Comment: Can you share the contents of `DATA.json` seems like that might not be an array. You could also use react dev tools to find out what you are actually passing to the data prop in your hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Live demo of the project fixed: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/refactor-pagination-mui-typescript-dwmtqk?file=/src/UsePagination.tsx)

In `App.tsx` the `Pagination` component should be set like this:

```
<Pagination count={totalPages} page={page} onChange={handleChange} />
```

You don't need to manually pass `event` and `page` to this `onChange` function because MUI will handle these internally. More specifically, it pass to the function which page is being changed to instead of the the current page.

This is the main reason why the `Pagination` was not functioning. I changed the title of cards to `item.title + "-" + item.id` so you can check the live demo to see it works.

**Syntax fixes**

I fixed some syntax error so there is no error message about types.

Changes made in `UsePagination.tsx`

```
// Need to check if data is provided
const maxPage = data ? Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage) : 1;

function currentData() {
  // Again this data may not be provided
  if (!data) return [];

  const begin = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
  const end = begin + itemsPerPage;
  return data.slice(begin, end);
}
```

Changes made in `App.tsx`:

```
// This function take an object as argument
const _DATA = usePagination({ data, itemsPerPage: PER_PAGE });
```

Comment: John the code working as I expected, thank you so much you saved me. Thank you again.

Comment: John I have another problem in the code. When I try to favorite a card it favorites the item per page and not the specific card. Could you help me with this other problem?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/refactor-pagination-mui-typescript-forked-j1psnj

Comment: The refactored code in codeSandbox with the favorite

Comment: @Paula Since this question post is specifically about the paging problem, do you mind considering to open another one about your new question for the community? This helps anyone who might have a similar situation to find a reference easily, and more from the community can look at the new problem and discuss to find the best solution for you too! Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I'll open another question. Thank you John you have helped me a lot.

Comment: @Paula Thanks! You can invite me to answer if you want, I'll do my best to help with the new question regarding favorite cards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437906/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-a-card-being-bookmarked-by-page-using-react-typescr

New question link