# How to solve the problem of a card being bookmarked by page using react, typescript and mui?

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, material-ui, frontend

When clicking on the card's favorite icon, I need to favorite only one card at a time, however, this does not happen. For example, if I click on the first card on any page, all other first cards are bookmarked. So I have the problem of cards being favorited per page and I want only what I clicked to be favorited.

To solve the problem in App.tsx -> CardAction I put the following code.

```
<Button size="small">
   <FavoriteIcon
   onClick={() => changeColorFavorite(id)}
   style={{ color: iconFavorite[id] ? "red" : "gray" }}
   Favorite
</Button>
```

I declared a useState by looping through the data(.json file) and setting false as the initial value for each card.

```
 const [iconFavorite, setIconFavorite] = useState(
    [...Array(data.length).keys()].map((i) => false)
  );
```

I also declared a function to change the state between true or false

```
 const changeColorFavorite = (id: number) => {
    const newIconFavorite = iconFavorite.slice();
    newIconFavorite[id] = !iconFavorite[id];
    setIconFavorite(newIconFavorite);
  };
```

How to solve this problem? Can someone help me please? Follow the code in codesandbox.

[Code codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-and-favorite-card-mui-typescript-j1psnj?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it happened**

The `id` passed to `changeColorFavorite` is actually the `index` of the array being mapped, hence the same order of card is marked as favorite on every page.

The function you used for the this map:

```
{_DATA.currentData().map((item, id) =>
```

It defines `id` as the `index` of `item` in this array. The actual value you are looking for should be `item.id`.

[More about `map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

**Solution**

Instead, pass `item.id` should get the desired result:

```
onClick={() => changeColorFavorite(item.id!)}
```

(I have to add `!` to override type check here, but you can refactor the `data` type later to make sure `id` is mandatory and is never `undefined`)

On top of that, the `onClick` is currently on your `FavoriteIcon`, but you might want to move it to the `Button` so that it does not just trigger by clicking on the icon:

```
<Button size="small" onClick={() => changeColorFavorite(item.id!)}>
  <FavoriteIcon style={{ color: iconFavorite[item.id!] ? "red" : "gray" }} />
  Favorite
</Button>
```

Hopefully this achieves the desired result without major changes.

That being said, I would suggest that the implementation of favorites could use some reconsideration in the future, if you need to expand more feature for those cards for example.

**Small refactor**

It seems that you're defining an array of `false` like this, and an error message occurs:

```
const [iconFavorite, setIconFavorite] = useState(
  [...Array(data.length).keys()].map((i) => false)
);
```

Despite that there might be better solution than handling these states as an array of `Boolean`, at this moment you could refactor the above code into this:

```
const [iconFavorite, setIconFavorite] = useState([...data].fill(false))
```

It does the same but cleaner and without error syntax.

[More about `fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you John Li. You helped me again.